# How to remove element from ArrayList without left shifting the rest of elements

Tags: java, arraylist

When you remove an element from an array list (`arrayList.remove(int n)`) it automatically shifts all the remaining elements to the left.

I was wondering is it possible for the elements to keep their position. So for example, if element at position 2 gets deleted, I want element at position 3 to remain where it is, not move to position 2. Thanks

Comment: what's the purpose of needing this functionality?  Are you iterating over a collection using a while statement?  Are you trying to modify during said iteration?  What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i need to retain the order as I have some methods that call the element at a certain position

Comment: so essentially you need to be able to modify an element as a specific position and retain the order/structure of the array as another method at an undetermined point in time may need to rely on said array and it must be configured to the correct size...etc?  If so, then the answer supplied is will absolutely work.  Once you've set the specific element to null the GC will pickup and cleanup the object that was formally stored at that location (or at least it should)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
list.set(2, null);
```

This just replaces the element at index 2 with null, which leads to the desired result.